# Difference between "$(shell ...)" and "$$(...)" in make

Tags: gnu-make

I am puzzled by the difference between the "`shell`" MAKE function and "`$$`". In the documentation I find:

> **The shell function** accepts a single argument that is expanded (like all arguments) and passed to a subshell for execution. The standard output of the command is then read and returned as the value of the function.

I believed this was *exactly* what "$$" was doing as well, however in this small example:

```
a = $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "Makefile")
b = $$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "Makefile")

.PHONY: all A B

all: A B

A: $(a)
    @echo "Target: $(@)"
    @echo "Prereq: $(<)"
    @echo "Var a:  $(a)"
    @echo "Var b:  $(b)"

B: $(b)
    @echo "Target: $(@)"
    @echo "Prereq: $(<)"
    @echo "Var a:  $(a)"
    @echo "Var b:  $(b)"
```

the output is the following:

```
Target: A
Prereq: Makefile
Var a:  ./Makefile
Var b:  ./Makefile
make: *** No rule to make target '$(find)', needed by 'B'.  Stop.
```

Note here that it says "No rule to make target **'$(find)'**", as if the argument has not yet been expanded. (I also tried to make the variable simply expanded, "`b:=$$(...)`", but this changed nothing).

I hope that someone has the knowledge to elaborate more on this, which to me seems like a subtle difference, but probably is much more profound than I can comprehend at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(shell ...)` is a Make **text function**.  Make will expand this, so in your example, `a` will expand, when substituted, to the *result* of the `find` command.  (If you made it a simply-expanded variable, the shell command would be evaluated only once, of course).

`$$` is just expanded to `$`, so in your example, `b` will substitute as the value `$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "Makefile")`.  This will be the same whether `b` is defined with `=` or `:=`.

When you use `$(b)` in a *command* such as `echo $(b)`, the *shell running that command* will see this as command substitution.  In other words, you have `echo $(find ...)` as a shell command.

Using `$(b)` in a Make target or dependency will, as you have seen, perform no further evaluation.

Here's another example Makefile, which I hope demonstrates what's going on.  We use single-quotes to show literally what the shell is given:

```make
a = $$(echo true)
b = $(shell echo true)

print:
    echo '$$a: $a' = "$a"
    echo '$$b: $b' = "$b"

.PHONY: print
```

This gives me

```
echo '$a: $(echo true)' = "$(echo true)"
$a: $(echo true) = true
echo '$b: true' = "true"
$b: true = true
```

showing that in the first case, the shell is given `$(echo true)` in its command, whereas in the second case, Make evaluates `echo true` and simply substitutes the result `true` into the command.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer, the example is excellent. I must admit that how make expands variables has always been somewhat magical to me.